# How can i calculate a non-weighted graph length for a path that is given

Tags: prolog

This is the code so far.

```
next_to(a, b).
next_to(a, c).
next_to(a, f).
next_to(b, c).
next_to(b, d).
next_to(b, e).
next_to(e, f).
next_to(g, h).

joint_with(X,Y):- next_to(X,Y) ;
    next_to(Y,X).

show_path(Node, FinishNode, [Node,FinishNode]) :-
        joint_with(Node, FinishNode).

show_path(Node, FinishNode, [Node | Restroute]) :-
        joint_with(Node, ANode),
        show_path(ANode, FinishNode, Restroute).
```

How can i change show_path to calculate the length aswell (Give explanation how it work's if possible thanks in advance)

Comment: Hint: use an extra parameter.

Comment: Moreover, this solution is not completely correct, it finds infinite paths

Answer (score 0):

According to Willem's advice, I constructed a solution for your problem which is the following:

```
next_to(a, b).
next_to(a, c).
next_to(a, f).
next_to(b, c).
next_to(b, d).
next_to(b, e).
next_to(e, f).
next_to(g, h).

joint_with(X, Y) :-
    (   next_to(X, Y)
    ;   next_to(Y, X)
    ).

show_path(Node, FinishNode, [Node, FinishNode], _) :-
    joint_with(Node, FinishNode).

show_path(Node, FinishNode, [Node|Restroute], Counter) :-
    joint_with(Node, ANode),
    show_path(ANode, FinishNode, Restroute, _),
    length([Node|Restroute], Counter),
    !.
```

But if backtracking doesn't  finish Counter does not take its value.